# How to change app's strings language after click on button?

Tags: java, android, string

I have problem with change strings language from default english to polish. I created `strings.xml(pl-rPL)` and I have method:

```
 public void setLocale() {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale("res/values-pl/strings.xml");
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

which I find somewhere on stackoverflow. Someone know why it doesn't change my strings after click on button? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I forgot add, that in Design xml file in AndroidStudio when I click `Locale in editor` and select PL language, strings are changing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: in the end of the method call 'recreate()' to recreate Activity and see changes

Comment: @Onik unfortunately it didn't help me